# Android + Retrofit - POST method throws... some unspecified thing

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I have an interface with a method defined like this:

```
@POST("/video/{id}")
public Float updateVideoRating(@Path(ID_PARAMETER) long id,
                                   @Body Float rating);
```

Now whenever I made a call to it:

```
public float uploadVideoRating(long videoId, float rating) {

    Log.d(TAG, "uploadVideoRating(" 
               + Long.toString(videoId) 
            + ", " 
            + Float.toString(rating) 
            + "): operation called");
    try {
        return mVideoServiceProxy.updateVideoRating(videoId, rating);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "uploadVideoRating(): exception caught: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0.0f;
    }
}
```

...I have following exception caught (plus couple of lines of stack trace):

```
07-15 22:48:34.317    2131-2131/? D/VideoDataMediator﹕ uploadVideoRating(1, 3.0): operation called
07-15 22:48:34.320    2131-2131/? E/VideoDataMediator﹕ uploadVideoRating(): exception caught: retrofit.RetrofitError 
07-15 22:48:34.320    2131-2131/? W/System.err﹕ retrofit.RetrofitError 
07-15 22:48:34.321    2131-2131/? W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400) 
07-15 22:48:34.321    2131-2131/? W/System.err﹕ at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) 
07-15 22:48:34.321    2131-2131/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397) 
07-15 22:48:34.321    2131-2131/? W/System.err﹕ at $Proxy0.updateVideoRating(Unknown Source) 
07-15 22:48:34.321    2131-2131/? W/System.err﹕ at pl.dropby.vduc.VideoDataMediator.uploadVideoRating(VideoDataMediator.java:176)
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect somewhere near "@Body" and "Float", but really dunno what...

Comment: You should change Float to float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make network calls on a background thread: you have this error: 
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I suggest you use the following code so you can focus on your client / server communications by making network calls on the main thread (GUI thread), and then do things properly through an asynctask or any other threading mechanism:

//TODO: remove the strictmode imports
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

//TODO: make sure the listview gets updated properly after returning from a VideoViewerActivity
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: that was it! after switching to making call from AsyncTask, everything worked almost fine. I've also changed interface a bit: `@POST("/video/{id}")
public Float updateVideoRating(@Path(ID_PARAMETER) long id,
                                   @Body float rating);` notice the change of Float to float ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not define the method like this:

```
@POST("/video/{id}/{rating}/")
public float updateVideoRating(@Path(ID_PARAMETER) long id, @Path(RATING_PARAMETER) float rating);
```

You don't need to put the rating in the body. You can access it via the path.

```
@RequestMapping(value=VideoSvcApi.VIDEO_DETAILS_PATH, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody float updateVideoRating(@PathVariable(VideoSvcApi.ID_PARAMETER) long videoId, 
                                                 @PathVariable(VideoSvcApi.RATING_PARAMETER) float rating, 
                                                 HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        if (videos.containsKey(videoId)) {
            return rating;
        }
        else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return null;
        }  
     }
```

Comment: it turned out that I was making network call on a main thread, instead of background one. anyway, thanks for help :)